# How can I disable to some directories for auto FTP sync in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, properties

I created a remote connection for my php project in NetBeans 8.0. I configured it to upload my files on save from "run configuration in properties. But I want some specific files or directories never to upload to server. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here's mine]

**Right Click** on your project and choose **Project Propertie**s, and go to **Ignored Folders**.
**Add Folders** to exclude your desired folders and **OK**